# Scrolling a second column if it overflows height of first

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am creating a row in Bootstrap 4 which has two columns.
The left column is formed of two Cards and the right column is one Card.

The left column's cards are both responsive embeds with iframes, using the embed-responsive-16by9 classes.

The right column is a simple card with a bullet point list. I want the right column to match the total 100% height of the leftmost column, and overflow with scroll if the list of bullet points get too long.

I have spent hours playing with flexboxes and overflows and all sorts and just cannot get this behaviour to work.

From the below code you can see #chatItems div has new items added to it throughout from javascript code.

With the file as attached the whole row becomes the height of the right hand column as the number of chatItem list items increases and doesn't start to scroll.

[Overall Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vygdF.jpg)

```
<div class="row pt-3">
<div class="col-md-9">

   <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal text-left text-uppercase">Video Player</h4>
            </div>  
          
            <div class="card-body embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">         
                <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/12345567895?autoplay=1&loop=1&autopause=0" width="100%" class="embed-responsive-item" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen autoplay></iframe>              
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
      
    <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal text-left text-uppercase">Video Player</h4>
            </div>
        
            <div class="card-body embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">         
                <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/12345567896?autoplay=1&loop=1&autopause=0" width="100%" class="embed-responsive-item" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen autoplay></iframe>              
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 ">
  <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal text-left text-uppercase">Chat Items</h4>
            </div>
        
            <div class="card-body p-0 overflow-y-scroll" id="chatItems">            
                <ul>
                    <li>First Item</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi there, Do please provide the code you are facing a problem with in order for us to help you.

Comment: Hi - I have added this! :)

Comment: @bh00s how about my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this...?

I've had to add some custom css to your chat card to handle overflow scrolling. `.overflow-y-scroll` class does not exist in bootstrap from what I can tell...

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/overflow/

In my example I've set the `.col-` classes to every screen size so the demo will work on here.

And I've given your chat card a min height of 300px incase you are viewing in mobile where it's parent column is a 100%. You change this of course.

See my demo below and a jsfiddle...

https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/2oy5kcfb/2/

```css
.card-chat {
  min-height: 300px;
  height: calc(100% - 1.5rem);
}

.card-chat .card-body {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.card-chat .card-body .list-group {
  top: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  bottom: -1px;
  font-size: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.card-chat .card-body .list-group-item:first-child,
.card-chat .card-body .list-group-item:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.card-video .card-body {
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row pt-3">
  
    <div class="col-8">

      <div class="card-video card mb-4 shadow-sm">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal text-left text-uppercase">Video Player</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/12345567895?autoplay=1&loop=1&autopause=0" class="embed-responsive-item" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen autoplay></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card-video card mb-4 shadow-sm">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal text-left text-uppercase">Video Player</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/12345567896?autoplay=1&loop=1&autopause=0" width="100%" class="embed-responsive-item" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen autoplay></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
    
      <div class="card-chat card mb-4 shadow-sm">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal text-left text-uppercase">Chat Items</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body p-0" id="chatItems">
          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```